# Trying to get panels to disappear with the click of a button

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working myself through this tutorial but I'm using jQuery and Bootstrap instead of what I think the author used, which was jQuery mobile? In any event I cannot get it to work. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cc3K2jDdKTo&list=UUVTlvUkGslCV_h-nSAId8Sw&index=97

When the user clicks Btn1 I want panel1 to disappear. Clicking Btn2 causes panel2 to disappear and so on. Could someone help me out on where I'm going wrong? Thank you.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <!-- Provides extra visual weight and identifies the primary action in a set of buttons -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" myPanel="panel1">Btn 1</button>

<!-- Secondary, outline button -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" myPanel="panel2">Btn 2</button>

<!-- Indicates a successful or positive action -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" myPanel="panel3">Btn 3</button>

<!-- Contextual button for informational alert messages -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" myPanel="panel4">Btn 4</button>

</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3" id="panel1">
            first panel
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3" id="panel2">
            second panel
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3" id="panel3">
            third panel
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3" id="panel4">
            fourth panel
        </div>
    </div> <!--/.row-->
</div> <!--/.container-->
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn").click(function(){
        var panelID = $(this).attr('myPanel');
        $('#' + panelId).toggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have variable name mistake `var panelID` you used as `panelId`.

```
$(".btn").click(function(){
    var panelID = $(this).attr('myPanel');
    $('#' + panelID).toggle();
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn").click(function(){
        var panelID = $(this).attr('myPanel');
        $('#' + panelID).toggle();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <!-- Provides extra visual weight and identifies the primary action in a set of buttons -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" myPanel="panel1">Btn 1</button>

<!-- Secondary, outline button -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" myPanel="panel2">Btn 2</button>

<!-- Indicates a successful or positive action -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" myPanel="panel3">Btn 3</button>

<!-- Contextual button for informational alert messages -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" myPanel="panel4">Btn 4</button>

</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3" id="panel1">
            first panel
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3" id="panel2">
            second panel
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3" id="panel3">
            third panel
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3" id="panel4">
            fourth panel
        </div>
    </div> <!--/.row-->
</div> <!--/.container-->
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title></title>  
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $( document ).ready(function() {
          // Handler for .ready() called.
            $( ".btn" ).each(function(index) { 
                $(this).on("click", function(){
                     var panelID = $(this).attr('data-panel'); 
                    $('#'+panelID).hide();
                });
            });
        }); 
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Provides extra visual weight and identifies the primary action in a set of buttons -->
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-panel="panel1" onclick="click();">Btn 1</button> 
            <!-- Secondary, outline button -->
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-panel="panel2">Btn 2</button> 
            <!-- Indicates a successful or positive action -->
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-panel="panel3">Btn 3</button> 
            <!-- Contextual button for informational alert messages -->
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-panel="panel4">Btn 4</button> 
        </div> 
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-3" id="panel1">  first panel  </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3" id="panel2">  second panel </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3" id="panel3">   third panel </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3" id="panel4">   fourth panel </div>
                </div> <!--/.row-->
            </div> <!--/.container-->
    </body>
</html>
```

please try this code